# Duvida SELECT Mysql

Tags: mysql, query, select, mariadb

Em um determinado select eu posso referencia duas tabelas pelas chaves estrangeiras.

Ex:IdA/ IdB

IdA = IdB

A tabela A tem uma coluna chamada C 
A tabela B tem três colunas chamadas D, E, F 
Ambas tabelas tem conteúdos similares para retorna no SELECT

Ex:

```
Select ... from table A a, table B b Where a.IdA = b.IdB and a.C = b.D and a.C = b.E and a.C = a.F...
```

Quando ponho a condição And retorna null
Quando ponho OR retorna dados incompletos, PQ?

Comment: Exemplifique melhor sua estrutura. Crie um [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Diga também, qual é o resultado que você quer!

Answer (score 1):

Quando vocês usa "and" todos as combinações tem que ser verdade(iguais no teu caso).

Já no OR a resposta da operação é verdade (1) se pelo menos uma das variáveis de entrada for verdade.

Por isso que no or funciona e no and está dando null

Comment: Se eu por A.c = B.d retorna mais valores do que as três sentenças com 'OR', quando no meu pensamento deveria retornar mais

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
Quando vc usa "AND", a busca retorna tudo que seja igual. Nesse caso, a.IdA = b.IdB "AND" a.C = b.D;
Isso esta dizendo que o resultado de que une a referencia a.IdA e b.IdB deve ser igual ao que une a.C e b.D;
No seu "WHERE" você esta fazendo isso para todas as tabelas a.IdA = b.IdB and a.C = b.D and a.C = b.E and a.C = a.F;
Logo, só vai ter um resultado, se por exemplo:
a.IdA = 1
b.IdB = 1
a.C = "TESTE"
b.D = "TESTE"
a.C = "TESTE"
b.E = "TESTE"
a.C = "TESTE"
a.F = "TESTE"
Quando você usa "OR", esta falando que pode retornar qualquer informação valida, exemplo:
a.IdA = 1
b.IdB = 1
a.C = "TESTE2"
b.D = "TESTE3"
a.C = "TESTE2"
b.E = "TESTE5"
a.C = "TESTE2"
a.F = "TESTE2"
Os resultados possíveis para " Where a.IdA = b.IdB or a.C = b.D or a.C = b.E or a.C = a.F"
1, TESTE2;
Aconselho usar "INNER" (join,left,right,outer), para unir tabelas de forma simples e organizada.
```